# Why do I see different files in Visual Studio Code terminal and Linux terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed that a lot of commands were missing when using VSCode terminal. So I tried a `ls -l /` on both my distro's and VSCode's terminals.

Linux Mint Xfce Terminal:

```
livy@linux-mint:~$ ls -l /
total 2097252
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Aug 13 15:13 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root       4096 Aug 13 15:15 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Aug 13 15:06 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root       4260 Aug 15 08:40 dev
drwxr-xr-x 147 root root      12288 Aug 13 16:46 etc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root       4096 Aug 13 15:06 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         33 Aug 13 15:07 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-54-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         33 Aug 13 15:04 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-54-generic
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root       4096 Aug 13 15:07 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Jul 29 19:15 lib64
drwx------   2 root root      16384 Aug 13 14:59 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Jul 29 19:14 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Jul 29 19:14 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 Aug 13 15:18 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 214 root root          0 Aug 15 08:40 proc
drwx------   4 root root       4096 Aug 13 15:07 root
drwxr-xr-x  32 root root        940 Aug 15 08:41 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root      12288 Aug 13 15:14 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Jul 29 19:14 srv
-rw-------   1 root root 2147483648 Aug 15 08:40 swapfile
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root          0 Aug 15 09:31 sys
drwxrwxrwt  15 root root       4096 Aug 15 08:53 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root       4096 Jul 29 19:14 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root       4096 Jul 29 19:50 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         30 Aug 13 15:07 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-54-generic
```

And here is the result from VSCode terminal:

```
livy@linux-mint:~$ ls -l /
total 2097204
drwxr-xr-x   6 nfsnobody nfsnobody       4096 Aug 13 16:00 app
lrwxrwxrwx   1 livy      livy               7 Aug 15 09:13 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 livy      livy              80 Aug 15 09:13 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 nfsnobody nfsnobody       4096 Aug 13 15:06 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x   5 livy      livy             340 Aug 15 09:13 dev
drwxr-xr-x  15 livy      livy             860 Aug 15 09:13 etc
drwxr-xr-x   4 nfsnobody nfsnobody       4096 Aug 13 15:06 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 livy      livy              33 Aug 15 09:13 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-54-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 livy      livy              33 Aug 15 09:13 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-54-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 livy      livy               7 Aug 15 09:13 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 livy      livy               9 Aug 15 09:13 lib64 -> usr/lib64
drwx------   2 nfsnobody nfsnobody      16384 Aug 13 14:59 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 nfsnobody nfsnobody       4096 Jul 29 19:14 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 nfsnobody nfsnobody       4096 Jul 29 19:14 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   3 nfsnobody nfsnobody       4096 Aug 13 15:18 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 209 nfsnobody nfsnobody          0 Aug 15 09:13 proc
drwxr-xr-x   6 livy      livy             160 Aug 15 09:13 run
lrwxrwxrwx   1 livy      livy               8 Aug 15 09:13 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 nfsnobody nfsnobody       4096 Jul 29 19:14 srv
-rw-------   1 nfsnobody nfsnobody 2147483648 Aug 15 08:40 swapfile
drwxr-xr-x   7 livy      livy             140 Aug 15 09:13 sys
drwxr-xr-x   4 livy      livy              80 Aug 15 09:13 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  12 nfsnobody nfsnobody       4096 Aug 13 16:00 usr
drwxr-xr-x   7 livy      livy             160 Aug 15 09:13 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 livy      livy              30 Aug 15 09:13 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-54-generic
```

From the file owners, permissions, and modification date... it looks like they are working on different file systems. VSCode's `/bin` even points to `/usr/bin`, while it is not the case in Xfce terminal. The strange thing is that I can still use VSCode's terminal to navigate my home directory (`/home/livy`) and make changes to files. It even sources the content of my `~/.bashrc` file.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having this exact same issue and discovered that the cause was that VSCode was installed as a Flatpak package. Uninstall it (be it a snap or a Flatpak package) and install the .deb file distributed by Microsoft.

Comment: Just put me off using flatpak forever!